# Jetbrains Intellij formatting code style issue

Tags: intellij-idea, formatting

I'm trying to change my code style, and I want to make method calls body in a new line.

There's an example of what I have and what I want to achieve.

[what I actually have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cq3CO.png)

[what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgHom.png)

actual:

```java
Optional<String> op = ch.getConfigurationSection("Tiers")
        .getKeys(false)
        .stream()
        .filter(s -> en.isCustomNameVisible() &&
                en.getCustomName().equalsIgnoreCase(
                        File.colored(ch.getString("Tiers." + s + ".hologramName"))))
        .findFirst();
```

what I want:

```java
.filter(s -> en.isCustomNameVisible() &&
        en.getCustomName().equalsIgnoreCase(
                File.colored(ch.getString("Tiers." + s + ".hologramName"))
        )
).findFirst();
```

Comment: It's very hard to compare your desired to your actual output. try either copying them to your question as text or inline them.

Comment: it is done @Alenros

Comment: What do you mean by `make method calls body in a new line`? Have you checked the options for Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Code Style | Java | Wrapping and Braces | **Method call arguments**, Method parentheses** and **Chained method calls**?

Comment: I want to make method parentheses in a new line according to opening paranthas.

Comment: Try Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Code Style | Java | Wrapping and Braces | Method call arguments | **Place ')' on new line** and **New line after '('**.